# doesnt boot anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

so i have a dual boot win7/ubuntu
installed on the same physical ssd, just other partitions.
i have others hdds, but not for data, not for boot.

a few weeks ago, while loging off ubuntu it showed a read/write error on sda4 (thats where linux is) then crashed.
it made it a few times over the weeks till last monday.
that day, grub asks me what system to boot. i choose ubuntu, then it went black, reboot screen bios and straight to ubuntu.

and yesterday, it didnt do anything.
no grub nothing.
i pluged off all my other hhds, then checked bios. bios sees the remaining ssd, had good temperature, everything normal. then restart.
and this time, it went straight to win7.
i made a checkdisk in there but nothing wrong.
and no way to go back to ubuntu.
and it crashed one more time in there while doing something. going to bootscreen and freezing there.

does that sound like an ssd fail to you ? or do you smell something else ?

thx guys

edit for the partition listing
no idea what loop 0-7 mean. the usb flashdrive ?

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   1.8G  1 loop /rofs
loop1    7:1    0    91M  1 loop /snap/core/6350
loop2    7:2    0  34.6M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop3    7:3    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
loop4    7:4    0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/260
loop5    7:5    0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/139
loop6    7:6    0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop7    7:7    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
sda      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0   128M  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0 186.6G  0 part /media/ubuntu/SYSTEM
├─sda4   8:4    0  55.9G  0 part /media/ubuntu/803cec2f-c456-40e1-a546-76351865a
├─sda5   8:5    0  59.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0 144.9G  0 part /media/ubuntu/ee69e151-628a-465f-a145-f7f8922dd
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0 927.8G  0 part
└─sdb2   8:18   0 935.3G  0 part
sdc      8:32   0 111.8G  0 disk
├─sdc1   8:33   0   100M  0 part
├─sdc2   8:34   0   128M  0 part
└─sdc3   8:35   0 111.6G  0 part
sdd      8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sdd1   8:49   0 443.2G  0 part
└─sdd2   8:50   0 488.3G  0 part
sde      8:64   1  15.2G  0 disk /cdrom
├─sde1   8:65   1   1.9G  0 part
└─sde2   8:66   1   2.4M  0 part

edit2:

now that im on win7, i find it to be slower than usual...

Comment: To help you it would help to show the partitioning of you SSD. Boot from a liveUSB and type `sudo lsblck`. Edit your question with the results.

Comment: edited with the listing. ;)
i rewired the other hdds meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

You could run boot-repair (see [Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair))

At my one time experience a SSD does not start to have issues as a harddrive does. A SSD either works fine or does not work at all.

Comment: yes, i thought so too.
but then, why would the win7 system be so slow ?  
win needs 5 minutes to load. blender needs 3 minutes.  
i ran a cystalmark test speed on the ssd, and the highest value i got was 350mb/s on read and 380mb/s on write...  
that seems pretty slow  
could the MB be at fault here?

Comment: I asume the spec's for your ssd specify higher read and write speeds. The reason why the speed is now lower, might be linked to why Win7 is loading and operating slower. Meaning that the test is not executed at a rate where it is fast enough to use the full capacity of your ssd.
I would create a live USB

Comment: to repair the MBR by running boot-repair.

But FIRST note your bitlocker key (if bitlocker is installed) and make a copy of the Win7 partition. Running a backup from Win7 includes rebooting and might leave you with unusable backups or even a completely failing system.
Then I would remove bitlocker (if installed). Mounting a partition protected by bitlocker is not possible. I found a solution for this, but avoiding the situation will be much easyer. (see   https://www.m3datarecovery.com/bitlocker-for-linux/access-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-linux.html)